# Using react-native-reanimated-carousel, I want to stop the animation in web and show all images but keep carousel animation in mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel, react-native-web, react-native-reanimated

I am using  react-native-reanimated-carousel for react native expo app for (IOS,Android, Web).
It is working fine in mobile view, but my requirement is that i should show all the elements in Web Browser, not the animation ( 1 element at a time).
`

```
<Carousel
                loop
                width={width}
                height={width / 2}
                autoPlay={true}
                data={[...new Array(6).keys()]}
                scrollAnimationDuration={1000}/>
```

I have only 4 images , so in web when app is opened in browser desktop,I want to show all the 4 elements at a time. Is there any way i can disable it in desktop browser?
Also How can I make wdith property to be responsive according to its image content?

I tried to add , remove properties, read documents

Comment: anyone knows solution or any direction?